# AIX kernel extension with system call

Tags: kernel-module, aix

According to the documentation here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/control-ibm-aix-kernel-extensions/
we've implemented a kernel extension and a loader that define and use a new system call.

The usage within the loader is implemented as here:

```
static size_t dtGetNumInterceptions() {
        void *libHandle = NULL;
        size_t (*ke_syscall)(void)=NULL;

        libHandle = dlopen( loadedExtension, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_MEMBER|RTLD_GLOBAL );
        if( libHandle ) {
                ke_syscall = dlsym(libHandle, "dtGetNumInterceptions");
                if( ke_syscall ) {
                        return ke_syscall();
                }
        }

        return (size_t)-1;
}
```

Comparing to another test application that was implemented with export and import files this function returns a bad result.

Where is the bug?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: There are 3 branches in your code which could return "bad result": 1. Failed `dlopen` 2. Failed `dlsym`. 3. Failed `ke_syscall`. So which one is **actually** failed?

Comment: Sorry, I have to clarify. Bad result means a wrong number. The kernel extension intercepty a systemcall und this new system call returns the number of interceptions 'til niow. It's a very simple one line function that retuirns the value of a counter.
When I call this function the normal way via export table, I get the correct result. When I call the function this way, I get 0 as a result. Obviously the function with that way has its own address space.

Comment: Please quote (or rather link) complete programs; IMHO you're doing something really dangerous without expertise.

Comment: That's not possible. The question is, is it possible, to execute a system call of a real kernel extension instance within a program whose main task is to load and unload a kernel extension.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example